# "then" is not exuceted after a Promise<void> when writing a file from a POST Request

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, post

I have currently an express server. I am trying to make a POST request without success.
Here is my ccontroller :

```
import { BAD_REQUEST } from '@app/constant';
import { SaveDrawService } from '@app/services/save-draw.service';
import { TYPES } from '@app/types';
import { Image } from '@common/communication/Image';
import { NextFunction, Request, Response, Router } from 'express';
import { inject, injectable } from 'inversify';
import 'reflect-metadata';

@injectable()
export class SaveDrawController {
    router: Router;

    constructor(@inject(TYPES.SaveDrawService) private saveDrawService: SaveDrawService) {
        this.configureRouter();
    }

    private configureRouter(): void {
        this.router = Router();
        this.router.post('/write', (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
            if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(BAD_REQUEST);
            this.saveDrawService.writeData(req.body as Image);
            return res.sendStatus(this.saveDrawService.code);
        });

        this.router.get('/read', (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
            return res.send(this.saveDrawService.readImageData());
        });
    }
}
```

Image here is a interface that i want to POST with these parameters:

```
export interface Image {
    title: string;
    tags: string[];
    data: string;   // base64 image from HTML canvas
}
```

Here is my service where I try to write the file :

```
import { ERROR, OK } from '@app/constant';
import { Image } from '@common/communication/Image';
import { readFile, writeFile } from 'fs';
import { injectable } from 'inversify';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import * as util from 'util';

@injectable()
export class SaveDrawService {
    code: number;
    constructor() {}

    async writeData(image: Image): Promise<void> {
        const base64Data = image.data.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
        const write = util.promisify(writeFile);
        return await write('test.png', base64Data, 'base64')
            .then(() => {
                this.code = OK; // 200
            })
            .catch((error: Error) => {
                console.error(error);
                this.code = ERROR; // 500
            });
    }

    async readImageData(): Promise<string> {
        const read = util.promisify(readFile);
        return await read('test.png', { encoding: 'base64' });
    }

    extractFormat(base64Data: string) {}
}
```

The problem is that the "then" in write is not executed after the write and the "this.code" is therefore never updated and makes the request crash. I just started and I really don't know what can be causing this.

Here is my request I make to test the code: [image]

On my server the POST is received and my server log this :
POST /api/draw/write 500 20.825 ms - 92

UPDATE: both my GET and POST return a error, but they are writing and reading the file on the server (I verify by making a POST and after a GET with logs to see if they are the same)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you should change. Don't use async/await with then/catch, these are two different notation to wait for asynchronous code and get data.

```
 async writeData(image: Image): Promise<void> {
        const base64Data = image.data.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
        const write = util.promisify(writeFile);
        const resp =  await write('test.png', base64Data, 'base64');
        
        if (resp.ok) // whatever your condition
        {
         this.code = OK;
        } else { 
           console.error(resp.error); // show error here
           this.code = ERROR;
        }
         
    }
```

Check here for more [details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).

Comment: Oh is see sorry for the long wait ! Gonna try this right now !

Comment: I finally sucessefully made it work with .then ! I dont know what was the problem, but yeah it help thanks you :D I could post the solution